# How to keep all my buttons middle of the region with vertical way In Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I have only 3 buttons inside a region.I want to keep all my buttons middle of the region with vertical way means in first row middle the button-1 should be place,then in 2nd row middle the button-2 should be place as per below picture.I can get only 2 option left & right with same row.so by clicking the buttons i can go to different different pages.

```
       +----------------------+
       |      Button-1        |   
       |      Button-2        | 
       |      Button-3        | 
       +----------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

- let all buttons start at new row
- set "column" value (for all of them) to 5 or 6

  - why? Because you have 12 columns available, so 5th or 6th will be in the middle of the region